# FocusLost at User Control [wpf]

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-controls, focus

FocusLost event is working on WPF's components properly
For User-Controls it is different:

if any control in the User-Control is clicked or focused, the User-Control's FocusLost is fired immediately ! How can I hinder it ?

I could not solve this problem :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` on the `UserControl` to determine if the `UserControl` or any of its children has the KeyBoard focus or not. There is also the event `IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged` which you can use, just check if `e.OldValue` is `true` and `e.NewValue` is `false` in the event handler.

**Edit**.
Here is an example of how you could make the `UserControl` raise a routed event (`UserControlLostFocus`) when `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` turns to false.

Useable like

```
<my:UserControl1 UserControlLostFocus="userControl11_UserControlLostFocus"
                 ../>
```

*Sample `UserControl`*

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent UserControlLostFocusEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("UserControlLostFocus",
                                         RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                                         typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
                                         typeof(UserControl1));
    public event RoutedEventHandler UserControlLostFocus
    {
        add { AddHandler(UserControlLostFocusEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(UserControlLostFocusEvent, value); }
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged += UserControl1_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged;
    }

    void UserControl1_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.OldValue == true && (bool)e.NewValue == false)
        {
            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(UserControl1.UserControlLostFocusEvent, this));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want anything to fire on focus being lost you can add this to the source .CS file behind the XAML User Control:

```
protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```